# ASP.NET MVC Return Comma Delimited String From From ListBoxFor To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a comma delimited string returned from a ListBoxFor and save it into our database. I use this later on in the program and break apart the string.

Here is what I have:

Model:

```
public string Mask_Concat { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="fancy-form" id="mainMask">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, "Mask(s)", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "chosen-container chosen-container-multi", @style = "width:300px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Mask_Concat")] Chip_Master chipMaster)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Chip_Master.Add(chipMaster);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(chipMaster);
}
```

Currently, I am only returning the first value in the multi-select.
Example: ListBoxFor is populated with mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4, mask5.

mask1 and mask5 are selected on the create.

When Mask_Concat makes it back to the controller, only mask1 is passed.

How can I pass the values as mask1,mask5?

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Through a save button:
                <div class="fancy-form">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: You can add a input hidden, and work with javascript to populate the field, whenever the selection changes. Then on submit, simply get the values from the hidden field.

Comment: care to explain? not exactly sure how to do that, or at least picturing it in my head I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I'll make an answer, wait a minute...

Comment: A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of values. Just change the property to `string[] Mask_Concat`, and if you want to save the values to string (instead of doing it the right way and using a relational table) then use `string value = String.Join(", ", chipMaster.Mask_Concat);` (and use `String.Split()` to reverse it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your HTML add a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedValues" name="selectedValues"/>
```

Add a class to your ListBoxFor

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "chosen-container chosen-container-multi change-select", @style = "width:300px"})
```

Here's the onchange method(jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('select .change-select').change(function () {
        var $hidden = $("#selectedValues");
        $hidden.val($(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(", "));
    });
</script>
```

Your controller is going to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Chip_Master chipMaster)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        chipMaster.Mask_Concat = Request.Form["selectedValues"];
        db.Chip_Master.Add(chipMaster);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(chipMaster);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, that javascript isn't working for me, and it is killing the rest of the javascript that is on my page.

Comment: What version of jquery are you utilizing