# ASP.NET, MVC ListBoxFor Edit "The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am receiving an error that I cannot figure out and even previously answered questions are not binding the ListBox the same way I am.

Here is how I use the ListBox on my create view:
[ASP.NET MVC Return Comma Delimited String From From ListBoxFor To Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575453/asp-net-mvc-return-comma-delimited-string-from-from-listboxfor-to-controller)

Now when I go to my edit I receive this error:

> The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when
>   multiple selection is allowed.

On this code:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "chosen-container chosen-container-multi", @style = "width:300px" })
```

I have tried everything I can think of, binding the  ListBox to a ViewModel, still no luck.

Model:

```
public string Mask_Concat { get; set; }
```

View:

```
                <div class="fancy-form" id="mainMask">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, "Mask(s)", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "chosen-container chosen-container-multi", @style = "width:300px" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mask_Concat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedMaskValues" name="selectedMaskValues" />
```

JS on view:

```
//join selected mask values
$("#Mask_Concat").chosen().change(function () {
    var $hidden = $("#selectedMaskValues");
    $hidden.val($(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(","));
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Chip_Master chipMaster = db.Chip_Master.Find(id);
    if (chipMaster == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.Manufacturer = new SelectList(db.Chip_Master, "Mask_Concat", "Mask_Concat", chipMaster.Mask_Concat.Split(',').ToList());
    return View(chipMaster);
}
```

Database:
Mask_Concat Column: 1234,5678,2345,7890

Thoughts? Need more information?

Answer (score 0):

`ListBoxFor` is used to display a *collection* of values.  You're trying to map it to a *single* string value.  I would add a property to your model that splits `Mask_Concat` into an array and bind *that* to the list box:

```
public string[] Mask_Concat_Values 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Mask_Concat.Split(','); 
    }
    set 
    {
        Mask_Concat = string.Join(",",values);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I include the "values" in the model?

Comment: So I just passed Mask_Concat as the values, now I do not get the error but the ListFor is blank and not populated with values.