# The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a MultiSelectList to a view and at the same time have the selected match up with the ids that are currently stored.

Problem is I get the error above and have spent the last couple of hours trying to solve it with no luck so asking for help.

In my class I have

```
public MultiSelectList ListOfNaceCodesUpdate { get; set; }
```

Controller I have

```
 List<string> codeIds = new List<string>();

                //Get current list of Ids in database
                foreach (var item in model.NaceCodes.Split('\n'))
                {
                    codeIds.Add(item);
                }

                List<string> arrayNaceToString = codeIds;

                var cmsGenericText = UmbracoAssignedContentHelperClass.PageContentByAlias("introduction");

                var returnNaceCodes = cmsGenericText.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("displayNaceCodes");

                List<GenericContent.TextValueViewModel> naceCodes = new List<GenericContent.TextValueViewModel>();
                //Get full list of codes
                foreach (var data in returnNaceCodes.ToContentSet())
                {
                    naceCodes.Add(new GenericContent.TextValueViewModel(text: data.GetPropertyValue<string>("category", string.Empty), value: data.GetPropertyValue<string>("code", string.Empty)));
                }

                MultiSelectList list = new MultiSelectList(naceCodes, "Text","Value",arrayNaceToString.ToArray());

                model.ListOfNaceCodesUpdate = list;
```

In View I have

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.NaceCodes, new MultiSelectList(Model.ListOfNaceCodesUpdate,"Value","Text"), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

But I keep getting:

> The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when
>   multiple selections are allowed.

I have looked at [ASP.NET, MVC ListBoxFor Edit "The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when multiple selection is allowed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927072/asp-net-mvc-listboxfor-edit-the-parameter-expression-must-evaluate-to-an-ien)

[SelectedValues not working in MultiSelectList mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826280/selectedvalues-not-working-in-multiselectlist-mvc)

[How can I create a SelectList with multiple selected values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839760/how-can-i-create-a-selectlist-with-multiple-selected-values)

But cannot work it out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This makes a lot of sense. The currently selected items (or item) must be read from `expression`. To facilitate this for a multiple selection, `expression` must return an `IEnumerable` so that the multiple items that could already be selected from it can be read.

It appears that your `NaceCodes` property is just a string, using some sort of arbitrary separator character within it. Are you able to make this an `IEnumerable` of some type instead - e.g. `List<String>` or `String[]`?

Alternatively, you could not have it directly related to the property and instead use [`ListBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listbox?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instead of `ListBoxFor()`. This is probably less preferable, because you likely want the selected elements to be properly bound to the model when the page is later posted, and an `IEnumerable` property is likely the simplest option for that.

Comment: Hi moreON, its returning a list, please see image added

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson - the `NaceCodes` property of the model, used in your code sample as `model.NaceCodes.Split('\n')`? It looks suspiciously stringy to me.

Comment: Hi moreOn, I'm getting confused, I'm returning a List<string> arrayNaceToString = codeIds;, which is the values from model.NaceCodes.Split('\n')

Comment: I need to have a rest, should have done public IEnumerable<string> NaceCodeList { get;set; } which solved the problem